# spring jpa data no default constructor

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i use spring jpa data,extend JpaRepository,and now i want to add new method,
the code is

```
public interface HighWayRepository extends JpaRepository<HighWay, String> {

    void updateNewHighWay(List<HighWay> mockedList);

}

public class HighWayRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<HighWay, String>
        implements HighWayRepository {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public HighWayRepositoryImpl(Class<HighWay> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.entityManager = em;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateNewHighWay(List<HighWay> mockedList) {

    }

}
```

and i use junit test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:conf/context.xml" })
@Component
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
@Transactional
public class HttpTest {
    @Resource
    private HighWayRepository repository;
     @test
     ......}
```

but it throw exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'httpTest': Injection of resource
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'highWayRepositoryImpl' defined in file
>   [D:\wyr\chinahighway\highway\target\classes\chinahighway\repository\impl\HighWayRepositoryImpl.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [chinahighway.repository.impl.HighWayRepositoryImpl]: No
>   default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   chinahighway.repository.impl.HighWayRepositoryImpl.()   at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
>     ... 25 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'highWayRepositoryImpl' defined in file
>   [D:\wyr\chinahighway\highway\target\classes\chinahighway\repository\impl\HighWayRepositoryImpl.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [chinahighway.repository.impl.HighWayRepositoryImpl]: No
>   default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   chinahighway.repository.impl.HighWayRepositoryImpl.()   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
>     ... 41 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [chinahighway.repository.impl.HighWayRepositoryImpl]: No
>   default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   chinahighway.repository.impl.HighWayRepositoryImpl.()   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
>     ... 57 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   chinahighway.repository.impl.HighWayRepositoryImpl.()   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2058)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
>     ... 58 more

i google the exception,and the reason is the HighWayRepositoryImpl class not have no arguments constructor,but i can't to add it.
how could run test normally?or maybe add what configure and annotation?

plz help me,thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Why do you need this method? Spring Data JPA will provide that one for you. You only need to extend the actual classes if you want a generic method to be available to all repositories. In your case there is no need (at least not from what you posted here).

Comment: thanks your comment,but the updateNewHighWay method is not only update it,it will add some logic

Comment: Then just do it in a seperate class you don't need to extend `SimpleJpaRepository` for that. See [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) section of the reference guide. Also **adding some logic** feels like you should be doing that in a service, not a repository or dao.

Comment: yes,and inject HighWayRepository into HighWayRepositoryImpl  to delegate it?

Comment: No... Have you read the link?